# How to find the RDD with smallest distance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, analysis

I have created an RDD of this type:

```
RDD[(Long, Iterable[(String, Double)])]
```

Here the first long parameter is the ID of the original point in map, second String parameter is an id of another point which is represented in String format from one fixed dataset. The third parameter Double is a distance between two points.

Now, I want to find minimum distance point for a given point. So, I want to convert this `RDD` to `RDD[(Long, (String, Double))]`. So, I will have all the points that are closest to the given set of points.

The output that I have at the moment is like this

```
(4516831,CompactBuffer((POI1,2632.0690038389157), (POI2,2632.0690038389157), (POI3,666.9416656643995), (POI4,1450.3241112528403)))
(4516915,CompactBuffer((POI1,2632.0690038389157), (POI2,2632.0690038389157), (POI3,666.9416656643995), (POI4,1450.3241112528403)))
```

The code that I tried to write is this.

```
`
// groupData returns output in the format RDD[(Long, (String, Double))]
val combinedData = groupData(dataRdd, poiRdd)
  .groupByKey()
  .map(row => {
    var min:Double = 9999999
    for(value <- row._2) yield
      if (value._2 < min) {
        min = value._2
      } else min
  (row._1, row._2.filter(r => r._2 == min))
  }).foreach(println)
// output like this: (4516915,List((POI3,666.9416656643995)))`
```

The above code works fine as per requirements but I think it is really bad, especially the last line where I am returning the output as I want. There I am filtering again.
There must be a better way.
How can I achieve this? I am sorry if the question is little vague.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a simple `map` function with `min` should work. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Do you have any code or a [mcve] you can provide.

Comment: Hi pault, thanks for your reply. I have updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: If the answer provided answers your question please accept it to close the question

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your sample input data is the intermediary data from `groupByKey`.  If so, let's say your original RDD is as follows:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (4516831, ("POI1", 2632.0690038389157)),
  (4516831, ("POI2", 2632.0690038389157)),
  (4516831, ("POI3", 666.9416656643995)),
  (4516831, ("POI4", 1450.3241112528403)),
  (4516915, ("POI1", 2632.0690038389157)),
  (4516915, ("POI2", 2632.0690038389157)),
  (4516915, ("POI3", 666.9416656643995)),
  (4516915, ("POI4", 1450.3241112528403))
))

val groupedRDD = rdd.groupByKey
// groupedRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Iterable[(String, Double)])] = ...
```

Then `groupedRDD` should have the exact same data as your sample input data.

You can then process groupedRDD's `mapValues` to capture the minimal value using `reduce` and wrap the reduced result in a `List` as per your output requirement:

```
val resultRDD1 = groupedRDD.mapValues( _.reduce{
    (acc, x) => if (x._2 < acc._2) x else acc
  }).map{ case (k, v) => (k, List(v))}

resultRDD1.collect
// res1: Array[(Int, List[(String, Double)])] = Array(
//   (4516915,List((POI3,666.9416656643995))), (4516831,List((POI3,666.9416656643995)))
// )
```

However, it would be more efficient if you can simply work from the original RDD data, and instead of using `groupByKey`, use the more performing `reduceByKey` as follows:

```
val resultRDD2 = rdd.reduceByKey(
    (acc, x) => if (x._2 < acc._2) x else acc
  ).map{ case (k, v) => (k, List(v))}

resultRDD2.collect
// res2: Array[(Int, List[(String, Double)])] = Array(
//   (4516915,List((POI3,666.9416656643995))), (4516831,List((POI3,666.9416656643995)))
// )
```

Comment: Hi Leo,Thanks for your response. I have printed some examples. I need final output as I got only need cleaner code.

Comment: @Piyush P, I see, you want the element of minimal value wrapped in a `List`.  Please see my revised answer.